# jqGrid navigator - how to specyfy settings globally?

Tags: jqgrid, navigator

I'm using [Navigator](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) with [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) and I'm repeating over and over settings such as:

```
savekey: [true, 13],
closeOnEscape: true,
closeAfterAdd: true
```

How can I define these settings globally to all my grids on current page?

I know how to specyfiy jqGrid settings globally, but I have problems with Navigator.
My sample Navigator definition looks like this:

```
    $("#dictionaryElementsGrid").navGrid(
        "#dictionaryElementsPager",
        {
            search: false,
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: true
        },
        {
            // Edit options:
            savekey: [true, 13],
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true
        },
        {
            // Create options:
            savekey: [true, 13],
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object `jQuery.jgrid.edit` is responsible for the default setting of Add and Edit forms, so you can include in your common JavaScript code the following:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    savekey: [true, 13],
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    recreateForm: true
});
```

The `recreateForm:true` option is another option which I recommend you to use if you use some events in the Edit or Add form.

Another settings `jQuery.jgrid.nav`, `jQuery.jgrid.del`, `jQuery.jgrid.view` and of course `jQuery.jgrid.defaults` can be also helpful and can be used in the same way as `jQuery.jgrid.edit` above. For example,

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.nav, {search: false});
```

The settings `edit:true`, `add:true`, `del:true` are already default (see [the source code of navGrid](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js#L1503))

Comment: Oleg, This is even more comprehensive answer than I ever expected. Many thanks for your effort.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately doesn't work: 
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.nav, {
    refresh: true,
    refreshicon: "custom-icon"
});
Tried this before and after I load grid itself, but nothing :(

Comment: @LifeIsShort: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which CSS framework you use (jQuery UI or Bootstrap)? Which `iconSet` you use? Which CSS rules exist on `custom-icon` class, which you want to use?... A demo, which reproduce the problem, would clear the most questions.