# Create base jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a website with several views, and most of them have a jqGrid on them.

I'd like to set some base options on all my jqgrids.  For example, I'd like the **view** option to always be set to true, and the **search** option to always be set to false.

Additionally, there are several that I'd like to have the same button labels.

Is there any way to do this with a jqGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional script tag to your HTML that references a JS file with some base configuration stuff for the grid in a $().ready(function() {}); block.

You could also create a base configuration function or variable that you store in that external JS, and reference that configuration on each view page.

I would prefer to write the base function, and not the ready event handler as the ready handler will NOT run at a predictable time.  You won't know if it properly ran before your jqGrid configure function ran.

Comment: Good idea.  I've spent most of my life on back end and I'm just playing around with front end stuff now so it's a bit unchartered territory.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032327/jqgrid-navigator-how-to-specyfy-settings-globally/5032879#5032879)  which shows how to set default settings `jQuery.jgrid.nav`. In your case it would be

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.nav,
    {search:false,view:true, viewtext:"View label", viewtitle:"View tooltip"}
);
```

Other default settings you can change in the same way using `jQuery.jgrid.del`, `jQuery.jgrid.view` and of course `jQuery.jgrid.defaults`.

You **don't need** to place the code inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {/**/});`. It is enough just ecxecute the code like `jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.nav, {search:false,view:true});` inside a JavaScript file loaded after the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.